# Magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1.1 upgrade fails, existing tables

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, upgrade, ce-1.9.1.1

I tried to upgrade from 1.9.0 to 1.9.1 a long time ago.
Unfortunatly there were some bugs in 1.9.1 which forced me to go back to 1.9.0.
Today I tried to upgrade from 1.9.0 to 1.9.1.1 which failed (internal server error due to existing tables).

I think my mistake was that i didnt restore my database too, so now i already have these tables of 1.9.1, causing an error.

Is there any way to solve that issue? Or is there any way to get my data (or at least parts of it) into a new magento installation?
Exporting and importing products, customers, etc using magento functions would be lots of work.

EDIT:
here is the error message (first three lines)
`a:5:{i:0;s:1064:"Error in file: "/var/www/vhosts/austrokamin.at/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'core_email_queue' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE core_email_queue (`

Comment: Can you paste here the errors you are getting? My suggestion is to try to clean the new tables you didn’t roll back when you downgraded the version.

Comment: My idea is that there are a lot more existing tables, after the first error the installation is aborted.
I have no idea which tables to delete.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have already made an attempt to upgrade once and left the old upgraded database. You original upgrade added or modified the tables so those "NEW" tables now exist and when you go to upgrade again Magento doesn't know they exist and it tries to create them.

You will need to walk through the upgrade and skip or modify the tables in question.

Comment: Have you got an idea how to do this?

Comment: you can just remove `core_email_queue` and `core_email_queue_recipients` two tables and refresh your home page to take it work